# How do I determine if different sections of a checkbox dropdown menu are selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiselect dropdown menu where each option has a checkbox and more than one option can be selected at once. I'm using a jQuery multiSelect plugin generate the dropdown.

```
<select id="types" multiple="multiple" size="5">
        <option value="">Show All</option>
        @{
            <option value="Gains">Gains</option>
            <option value="Losses">Losses</option>
            <option value="Adjustments">Adjustments</option>
            <option value="Future">Future</option>

            <option value="Deliveries">Deliveries</option>
            <option value="Recoveries">Recoveries</option>
            <option value="Full Payout">Full Payout</option>
            <option value="Early Payout">Early Payout</option>
            <option value="Charge Offs">Charge Offs</option>
            <option value="Returns">Returns</option>
            <option value="Transfers">Transfers</option>
            <option value="Ins. Write-offs">Ins. Write-offs</option>
        }
    </select>
```

What I need to be able to do is separate the options into 2 sections. The first 4 in a section and the last 8 in a section. If an option is selected in one section, then any options that are selected in the other section are then unselected. This is already setup in a C# .NET application. I am having to replicate the functionality. I don't have access to the .NET code. At first I thought maybe I could put the different options into separate divs and just check whether an option was selected in each div but I get validation errors when I try to do that. I'm not really sure what else I could try. Any help with this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some code so it's easier to see what you are doing?

Comment: What kind of validation errors?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: Show us the code you're currently using for that. Also, such a complex logic should better not be presented in a dropdown. Or make an extra switch about which section to use and then show different dropdowns for each one.

Comment: Definitely need to post more code that you've actually attempted, but look into `<optgroup>`

Comment: *Which*  multiselect dropdown are you using? Show us your JS code as well, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using classes, attach a jquery check box `click()`, check for class `if ( $(this).hasClass("checkboxSection1") )` then uncheck all the other ones like so `$(".checkboxSection2").prop('checked', false);`

so some simple code is

```
$("myForm :checkbox").click( function(){
   $(this).hasClass("checkboxSection1")?
       $(".checkboxSection2").prop('checked', false):
       $(".checkboxSection1").prop('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about giving them a set of classes e.g. 'option1' & 'option2', then you can do a little javascript/jquery to handle the logic of the selection process...